# Unable to change template with reactive forms

Tags: angular

I'm trying to change the template of a reactive form in Angular 2. I have created a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/dJ1KyDLFDOOa1FUfWu5d?p=preview). You can see the error by clicking the button and looking at your console.

My initial template is as follow:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.array([
      this.formBuilder.group({
        answer:this.formBuilder.array([[''], [''], ['']]),
        type:['group']
      }),
      this.formBuilder.group({
        answer:[''],
        type:['control']
      }),
      this.formBuilder.group({
        answer:this.formBuilder.array([[''], [''], ['']]),
        type:['group']
      })
 ]);
```

After clicking the button, the form becomes:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.array([
  this.formBuilder.group({
    answer:[''],
    type:['control']
  }),
  this.formBuilder.group({
    answer:this.formBuilder.array([[''], [''], ['']]),
    type:['group']
  }),
  this.formBuilder.group({
    answer:[''],
    type:['control']
  })
]);
```

Here is the html code:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of form.controls; let idx=index" [formGroupName]="idx">
    <div *ngIf='item.controls.type.value == "control"'>
       <div>Input</div>
       <input name="answer" type="text" placeholder="Reponse" formControlName="answer"/>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf='item.controls.type.value == "group"' formGroupName="answer">
       <div>Checkboxes</div>
       <div *ngFor='let ctrl of item.controls.answer.controls; let index=index'>
          <input name="answer" type="checkbox" placeholder="Reponse" [formControlName]="index"/>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that solution will be good for you, but you could create 2 forms, and just switch between them by using `*ngIf` directive.

Here's [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/YsxnFJzneQQxRMIQPbYs?p=preview) with an example.